# Malware in a PDF

Tags: malware, pdf

I opened a PDF yesterday.

How large would a PDF be that has malware? The one I downloaded was approximately 5 MB.

If I opened the PDF on a browser, would the browser be infected?

For some context: I had uploaded the file to Virustotal yet it yielded no results for viruses, however something about the sandbox would not load, which leads me to believe that the file is infected. When I downloaded the PDF, my PC seemed to have used all its memory, allowing the PDF to bypass my antivirus scanner.

Comment: Upload to https://cuckoo.ee/ or a malware sandbox

Comment: Could the browser be infected? It depends on what the malware is designed to do.

Comment: Welcome to the community. A file size doesn't collerate to it being malicious or safe..

Comment: You can have a legit 4GB PDF and an infected 10kb PDF file... Size does not mean anything.